# MapServer won't open multiple layer with STATUS on

Tags: mapserver

So I made this mapfile and I tried to load multiple layers with status set to on but that doesn't work.  The layers with "STATUS DEFAULT" load but the other two won't when I change the URL.

```
#### places LAYER
  LAYER   NAME  "places"
          TYPE           polygon
          DATA           "places"
          STATUS         DEFAULT
            CLASS
                  STYLE
                          COLOR           "#b2b266"
                          OUTLINECOLOR    "#331a00"
                  END
          END
  END
  #### water LAYER
  LAYER  NAME "water"
         TYPE         polygon
         DATA         "water"
         STATUS       ON
         CLASS
                STYLE
                        COLOR               "#1a8cff"
                        OUTLINECOLOR        "#00264d"
                END
        END
  END
  #### railroads LAYER
  LAYER  NAME "railways"
          TYPE             LINE
          DATA            "railways"
          STATUS        ON
          CLASS
                  STYLE
                          COLOR              "#ff6600"
                          SIZE                    3
                          SYMBOL              "line7"
                  END
          END
  END
```

If I set "LAYERS=water" or "LAYERS=railways" the layers will load but "LAYERS=water,railways" won't with the URL:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/MyProject/project.map&layers=water,railways&mode=map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use mode=map you have to separate layer names by space not comma.
In your case:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/MyProject/project.map&layers=water railways&mode=map
```

Or you can use more layer=name parameters in the query string:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/MyProject/project.map&layer=water&layer=railways&mode=map
```

Comment: The question is about CGI MapServer not WMS and it works for me (Ubuntu 16.04 and MapServer 7.0.7).  Quote from MapServer docs: LAYERS [name name ...]

    The names of the layers to be turned on. Layer names must be separated by spaces.

Comment: The answer is correct, I hope that the one who downvoted will take it back.